# Prove that $(A\setminus B)\cup (B \setminus A)\subseteq (A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I am asked to prove that

$$
(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)\subseteq (A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are sets. Could someone please check my solution and see if it is correct?

I suppose that sets $A$ and $B$ are subsets of a global set $X$. Fix $x\in (A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$. Then

$$
\begin{align}
x\in (A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)&\Rightarrow
x\in A\setminus B\text{ or }x\in B\setminus A\\
&\Rightarrow
(x\in A\text{ and }x\not\in B)\text{ or }(x\in B \text{ and }
x\not\in A)\\
&\Rightarrow
[(x\in A\text{ and }x\not\in B)\text{ or }x\in B]\text{ and }
[(x\in A\text{ and }x\not\in B)\text{ or }x\not\in A]\\
&\Rightarrow
[(x\in A\text{ or }x\in B) \text{ and }
(x\in B\text{ or }x\not\in B)]\text{ and }\\
&\qquad
[(x\in A\text{ or }x\not\in A)\text{ and }
(x\not\in A\text{ or }x\not\in B)]\\
&\Rightarrow
[(x\in A\cup B \text{ and }
(x\in B\text{ or }x\in X\setminus B)]\text{ and }\\
&\qquad
[(x\in A\text{ or }x\in X\setminus A)\text{ and }
\neg(x\in A\text{ and }x\in B)]\\
&\Rightarrow
[x\in A\cup B \text{ and }
x\in B\cup(X\setminus B)] \text{ and }\\
&\qquad
[x\in A\cup(X\setminus A)\text{ and }\neg(x\in A\cap B)]\\
&\Rightarrow
[x\in A\cup B \text{ and }x\in X]\text{ and }
[x\in X\text{ and }x\not\in A\cap B]\\
&\Rightarrow x\in A\cup B\text{ and }
x\not\in A\cap B\\
&\Rightarrow x\in(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Please use $A \setminus B$ (' A\setminus B') instead of $A /B$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Fixed it.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri where?

Comment: How did you get this in the third line:$$[(x\in A\text{ and }x\not\in B)\text{ or }x\in B]\text{ and }
[(x\in A\text{ and }x\not\in B)\text{ or }x\not\in A]$$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I do not see why that is illegal.

Comment: Nevermind, I thought you used the distributive property. The proof is correct, although I see a lot of unnecessary details; for example, $x\in B\text{ or }x\notin B$ is a true statement, and you seemed to have overcomplicated reaching that inference.